# WCF Service (IIS) with backup ports

Tags: wcf, iis

I got a webservice hosted on an IIS. At the moment it runs on a highport above 60k.
Let's say that port is blocked by the firewall on the client side and I want to configure some backup ports. Skype does that for example. It runs on port 21850 and got port 80 and 443 as backup ports. What would be the progress on the Server side (IIS + webconfig) to listen to several ports.

Can I simply add in the sidebindings dialog another few addresses just with a different port and add them in the baseAdresses section in the web.config?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: It works as described above. Ensure you restart your website though in the IIS.

Comment: The answer is "yes". If you know how to do it, why do you ask random strangers on the internet instead of just testing it for yourself?

Comment: Because I tried already, but experienced issues. Required adding multipleSiteBindingsEnabled = "true" additionally to the webconfig for me and website required a restart. Thanks anyway.